# grid.grab(): strange behavior of "wrap" argument when working with lattice output

Tags: r, lattice, r-grid

`grid.grab()` captures all of the current viewports and stores them as a grob. In theory, and often in practice, you can use `grid.grab()` to store an image now for drawing later on. But I have noticed some odd behavior of `grid.grab()` when working with lattice output. It is related to the `wrap` argument:

1. When `wrap = TRUE`, the saved grob should produce a drawing faithful to the original viewports. But sometimes it doesn't.
2. Even when using `wrap = TRUE`, `grid.grab()` warns me to use `wrap = TRUE`.

Here is a minimal example to illustrate these behaviors:

```
library(grid)
library(lattice)
xyplot(1:5 ~ 1:5)
trellis.focus()
panel.abline(h = 3)
panel.abline(h = 5)
myGrob <- grid.grab(wrap = TRUE)
```

At this point, I receive a warning—

```
In grabDL(warn, wrap, ...) :
  one of more grobs overwritten (grab WILL not be faithful; try 'wrap = TRUE')
```

—which is strange, given that I specified `wrap = TRUE`.

I proceed by running

```
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(myGrob)
```

According to Paul Murrell (*R Graphics,* 2nd ed., page 239), using `grid.grab(wrap = TRUE)` is "guaranteed to replicate the original output." But it doesn't. Specifically, the top horizontal line (from `panel.abline(h = 5)`) isn't reproduced.

I've run this example in R 3.3.2 and 3.5.1. It comes out the same in both cases. Are these bugs, or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Paul Murrell answered the question](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2018-October/457023.html) on the R-help mailing list. In short, the problem arises because, in the example above, the code creates two grobs with the same name, which in turn causes problems with `grid.grab()`. In his answer, Paul suggests that one workaround is to name the second grob: replace

```
panel.abline(h = 5)
```

with

```
panel.abline(h = 5, identifier = "abline2")
```

and there are no problems. (I've verified that this solution works.) Paul also notes that a coming version of `grid.grab()` will be better able to handle cases like the one that I described above.